# Reference to the value of input field

Tags: javascript, reference

Consider the following code snippet:

```
inputTextField=document.getElementById("Phone_input");
var value = inputTextField.value; 
value=value.substring(0,10);
```

where `Phone_input` is an `<input type="text"/>` element. Why during the running of this script there is no changes of actual value of the `<input type="text"/>`. We're changing value by the reference which indicates to `inputTextField.value`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `value` is not a reference, so after the change you must write it back into the textfield:

```
value=value.substring(0,10);
inputTextField.value = value;
```

Or, in one line:

```
inputTextField.value = inputTextField.value.substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript always passes by value, but in an array or object, the value is a reference to it, so you can 'change' the contents.
In this case you have to do it this way:

```
var inputTextField=document.getElementById("Phone_input");
inputTextField.value = inputTextField.value.substring(0,10);
```